# Python unicode vs utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, repr

I am building a string query (cypher query) to execute it against a database (Neo4J).

I need to concatenate some strings but I am having trouble with encoding. 
I am trying to build a unicode string.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
value = u"D'Santana Carlos Lãnez"
key = u"Name"
line =  key + u" = "+ repr(value)
print line.encode("utf-8")
```

I expected to have:

> Name = "D'Santana Carlos Lãnez"

But i getting:

> Name = u"D'Santana Carlos L\xe3nez"

I imagine that `repr` is returning a unicode. Or probably i am not using the right function.

Comment: Uhh, what are you using repr for? `line =  key + u" = " + value`.

Comment: I am using `repr` to espace characters as backslash and quotes.

Comment: Yes and I am asking why you are doing that.

Comment: Because I want to send this string to the database (Neo4j). So I need it surrounded by quotes or single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python literal (`repr`) syntax is not a valid substitute for Cypher string literal syntax. The leading `u` is only one of the differences between them; notably, Cypher string literals don't have `\x` escapes, which Python will use for characters between U+0080–U+00FF.

If you need to create Cypher string literals from Python strings you would need to write your own string escaping function that writes output matching [that syntax](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html#_note_on_string_literals). But you should generally avoid creating queries from variable input. As with SQL databases, the better answer is [query parameterisation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to use query parameterization, but I am using py2neo and my queries are more complicated. I am doing a bulkload so I can not use the query parameterization resource.

Answer (score 1):

`value` is already unicode because you use prefix `u` in `u"..."` so you don't need `repr()` (and `unicode()` or `decode()`)

Besides `repr()` doesn't convert to unicode. But it returns string very useful for debuging - it shows hex codes of native chars and other things.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = u"D'Santana Carlos Lãnez"
key = u"Name"
line = key + u" = "+ value
print(line)
```